# How to determine PATCH request inside method Update DRF serializer

Tags: python, rest, api, serialization, django-rest-framework

Or what is the best solution for this task?

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    )
    serializer_class = MyViewSerializer
    pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination
```

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
    instance.content = validated_data.get('content', instance.content)
    instance.created = validated_data.get('created', instance.created)
    return instance
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest method would be sending method in serializer context and getting it in `update` method.

```
serialized = YourSerializer(obj, request.data, context={'method': request.method}
```

in your update function

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    method = self.context.get('method')
    # your rest of the update method
```

**Or**

If you are not sending context to your serializer from view, by default request object is send in context. You can get it from there as well.

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    method = self.context.get('request').method
    # your rest of the update method
```

Comment: There is not `method`.

Comment: Which `method` you are talking about? `request.method`? or `method` in update method?

Comment: `method = self.context.get('method')` return `None`. There is only ``` {'request': <rest_framework.request.Request object at 0x7faf1a2791d0>, 'format': None, 'view': <fbp.pricing.views.myView.ViewSet object at 0x7faf1a26ffd0>}```

Comment: You will have to send that from your view. As I mentioned in my answer.
`serialized = YourSerializer(obj, request.data, context={'method': request.method}
`

Comment: Thank you! I added my View above. Where i should pass `context={'method': request.method}` to to Serializer?

Comment: You can use second method in your case that I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this link is useful [WritableNestedModelSerializer](https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested)